# how to specify attribute of GNU C?

Tags: attributes, gnu, function-attributes

In [GUN C manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/), *6.30 Declaring Attributes of Functions*, it states:

> You may also specify attributes with `__` preceding and following each keyword. This allows you to use them in header files without being concerned about a possible macro of the same name. For example, you may use `__noreturn__` instead of `noreturn`.

Does this mean that user can specify customized attributes?  Or what else?  I'm definitely confused, could anyone help, or give me some samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it's saying is that a header file might have done:

```
#define noreturn 3
```

If you then try to declare a function as:

```
void fatal () __attribute__ ((noreturn));
```

it will be processed as if you'd written:

```
void fatal () __attribute__ ((3));
```

which is not what you want. So you can write instead:

```
void fatal () __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));
```

This is safe because users are not allowed to define macros with names beginning with two underscores, these names are reserved for the implementation. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: Hi, @Barmar, thank you:), in your reply, *users are not allowed to define macros with names beginning with two underscores*, I test on gcc v4.7.2, with `#define __foo__ 2`, and this is fine with `gcc -Wall test.c`.  Does this limitation just coding conversion or GNU limitation?  or something else?

Comment: They're programming restrictions specified by the language. See the question I just added a link to.